# List of all current Font Awesome icons in a more easily visible format?

Tags: font-awesome

I love me some [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), but [the page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/) that shows all the icons isn't effective for browsing.

[image]

In Chrome on OS X all the icons are very small, and trying to scan through visually to find an icon I want is difficult.

I'd love to browse all the icons by themselves, on a page where the icons are more on the range of ~20+ pixels wide. Merely increasing the zoom level in my browser just doesn't help. Does such a display exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GlyphSearch.com](http://glyphsearch.com/)

Displays glyphs from a few different libraries, is searchable and can copy the class directly to your clipboard.